# Artificially increasing the region of interest of an image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

I am solving an image segmentation problem. To increase the accuracy of the model, I came across the following preprocessing step-

> First, the set of pixels of the exterior border of the ROI is de
>   termined, i.e., pixels that are outside the ROI and are neighbors
>   (using four-neighborhood) to pixels inside it. Then, each pixel value
>   of this set is replaced with the mean value of its neighbors (this
>   time using eight-neighborhood) inside the ROI. Finally, the ROI is
>   expanded by inclusion of this altered set of pixels. This process is
>   repeated and can be seen as artificially increasing the ROI.

The image after applying the following step is below-
[image]

The image I am applying the above step is below-
[image]

On asking the question [here](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/9194/artificially-increase-the-region-of-interest-of-an-image/9195?noredirect=1#comment13872_9195), I got the initial approach to take the black area surrounding my image and use it as a alpha mask.

My approach to solve this problem is to find all the boundary pixels(outside the FOV) which is the first black pixels outside the red part which I obtained using the below code-

```
    my_list = []
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        if (j+1)<=564:
            if (img[i][j+1]==255) and (img[i][j-1]!=255):
                my_list.append([i,j])
        elif (j+1)<=564:
            if img[i][j+1]==0 and img[i][j]!=0:
                my_list.append([i,j])
        elif (i-1)>=0:
            if img[i-1][j]==255 and img[i][j]==0 :
                my_list.append([i,j])
        elif (i+1) >=0:
            if img[i+1][j]==255 and img[i][j]==0:
                my_list.append([i,j])
```

My idea behind the above code is, I can divide the mask in 4 sections and then can find the boundary pixels according to that-
I have marked 4 sections below(Apologies for the poor illustration)-

[image]

Now, after determining the boundary pixels outside the FOV, I need to replace them with mean of neighbour pixels (8-neighbours) which will be the mean of 3 pixels in this case as the pixel which we are modifying will always be in the corner as shown below-

[image]

So my questions are-

1)Is my thought process correct?
2)I don't know how to modify the pixels with neighbourhood pixels?
Any other approach to solve it is also welcomed.

Edit---Solution to the problem according to the answer

```
 while(notroi):
    border_pixels = []
    for i in range(img.size[0]):
        for j in range(img.size[1]):
            if [i,j] not in roi and ([i+1, j] in roi or [i-1, j] in roi or [i, j+1] in roi or [i, j-1] in roi):
                border_pixels.append([i,j])

    for (each_i,each_j) in border_pixels:
        color_sum = 0
        count = 1
        eight_neighbourhood = [[each_i-1,each_j],[each_i+1,each_j],[each_i,each_j-1],[each_i,each_j+1],[each_i-1,each_j-1],[each_i-1,each_j+1],[each_i+1,each_j-1],[each_i+1,each_j+1]]
        for pix_i,pix_j in eight_neighbourhood:
            if (pix_i,pix_j) in roi:
                color_sum+=pixelMap[pix_i,pix_j]
                count+=1
        pixelMap[each_i,each_j]=(color_sum//count)

    for (each_i,each_j) in border_pixels:
        roi.append([each_i,each_j])
        border_pixels.remove([each_i,each_j])
        notroi = notroi-1
        print(notroi)
```

Edit:
Image obtained-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you cited is actually much simpler. If you have the original ROI as a per-pixel mask, then the algorithm looks like this in pseudo-code (boundary-handling omitted for clarity):

```
while there are pixels not in the ROI:
    border_pixels = []

    # find the border pixels
    for each pixel p=(i, j) in image
        if p is not in ROI and ((i+1, j) in ROI or (i-1, j) in ROI or (i, j+1) in ROI or (i, j-1) in ROI)):
            add p to border_pixels

    # calculate the averages
    for each pixel p in border_pixels:
        color_sum = (0, 0, 0)
        count = 0
        for each pixel n in 8-neighborhood of p:
            if n in ROI:
                color_sum += color(n)
                count += 1
        color(p) = color_sum / count

    # update the ROI
    for each pixel p=(i, j) in border_pixels:
        set p to be in ROI
```

Comment: but how to determine 8-neighbourhood of p and also how to dynamically determine the ROI as you are showing in the pseudocode

Comment: The ROI can initially just be all the black pixels (as far as I see). The Graphics.SE answer also mentioned some other possibilities. The 8-neighborhood is the same as the 4-neighborhood we used for finding the border pixels, but including the diagonals `(i-1, j-1), (i+1, j-1)...` I simply did not want to list them all in the code.

Comment: Thanks but I am really not able to understand. ROI in my case is the white portion or the red portion of the complete image, so really not able to understand how to determine it.

Comment: I'm not sure where your misunderstanding lies. When creating the mask, simply do something like `for each pixel: if pixel is red or white or whatever: set pixel to be in ROI`.

Comment: okay, one last point, what is color in `color_sum += color(n)`

Comment: The color of pixel `n`.

Comment: Hi, so I implemented the code according to your pseudocode but I don't how to write the first loop `while there are pixels not in the ROI:`. Also, the above code is taking too much time to execute.

Comment: Simplest thing to do would be to count the pixels that are not in the ROI when you set it up. Then, every time you add a pixel to the ROI, decrement the counter and loop as long as the counter is greater than zero. If you have working code, then post it so people can suggest improvements. [codereview.se] is most appropriate for that.

Comment: Okay, few more problems I am facing. The output is not intended it should be after running the algorithm. Also, how the propagate the results calculated in the alpha mask(black and white image) to the original image. I am adding the image I obtained and the code which I used.

Comment: Okay, there is a issue with the termination condition, we don't want the circular roi to fully fill the complete rectangular image so running loop till the end of roi is not a good terminating condition

Comment: If you don't want that, then simply store the distance from the ROI for each pixel. You can approximate this incrementally when you set a new pixel: The distance of the new pixel is the minimum distance of its source pixels + 1. And then abort as soon as you exceed a threshold.